# Debugging what has been submitted in a form

Tags: 7, blocks, forms

I would like to like to be able to print out what has been submitted in my form in the submission form. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this a form created yourself, or do you want to hook into a form defined in another module? Is this for debugging purposes, or do you actually want the site to show this data to the end user?

Comment: a form that I created for debugging process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can display the submitted values in your `hook_form_submit()` and set it like this (example):

```
function form_example_tutorial_7_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted. name="@first @last", year of birth=@year_of_birth', array(
   '@first' => $form_state['values']['first'],
   '@last' => $form_state['values']['last'],
   '@year_of_birth' => $form_state['values']['year_of_birth'],
  )));
}
```

Comment: You can also use dpm function from devel module. It prints using Krumo all kind of variables, complex arrays included. So you can just dpm the $form_state in the submit handler as Djouuuuh suggests.

Comment: OKaaayyy! I didn't know it was for debugging process. Of course use dpm with Devel module in the hook I suggested you. It's way easier.

Comment: I really recommend spending some time setting up XDebug and using that. Here are some links. If you use a good IDE, like PHPStorm, you get great integration with XDebug and no need to mess up your code with debugging statements. :) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/xdebug-professional-php-debugging--net-34396  http://xdebug.org/docs/install https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUTolQw8K9A

Answer (score 2):

Its better to install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and use the dpm function.

```
function MYMODULE_FORMID_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm(hook_form_id_submit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing stuff in the page output, I would recommend to use an IDE such as PhpStorm, Eclipse or Netbeans. Combined with Xdebug, you can set a breakpoint in the form submit function and inspect all variables available at that point. You'll find the submitted values in `$form_State['values']`.